# In order to sort geoquery results by distance must I read the entire dataset?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, geofire, geofirestore

To perform geoqueries in Firebase or Firestore, there are libraries like GeoFire and GeoFirestore. But to sort the results of that geoquery by distance, the entire dataset must be read, correct? If a geoquery produces a large number of results, there is no way to paginate those results (on the backend, not to the user) when sorting by distance, is there?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in order to sort by distance you must read all results that fall into the Geoquery range.

The reason for this is how such queries work: they return a set of documents that are within a range of geohash values, which is not necessarily the same order as by their distance to the center of the query.

This also means that there is no way to do meaningful pagination in a list of documents that are ordered by their distance, since you need to read all results anyway. The best I can think of is implementing the Geoquery in Cloud Functions, so that you can do the sort/filter there, and only **return** the page-full of results to the client. While this doesn't save on your cost (as you're still reading all documents in the range), it will save bandwidth in sending documents to the user.

To learn more about how such geoqueries work, which explains why they can't be optimized the way you're looking to do, have a look at the video of my talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q) or [this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/geolocation-query-in-firestore-realtime/) article+shorter video on Jeff Delaney's site.

Comment: Hi...looking at your video i understand this firestore limitation is still present cause of the still single range comparison in one query : for filtering documents within a radius by distance, we still need to fetch all documents present in geohashes covering this radius...and so still pagination cant be implemented : is that still valid?
For a production app as location based riding/delivery app, i am trying the evaluation if the overcost make it viable to choose Firestore from a SQL DB? are other developpers still opting in in such case?

Comment: Yes, all of those still apply, and they're unlikely to ever change when using geohashes to perform geoqueries. Recommending other options is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but search engines are great for that.