# Im using geofirestore with firestore and want to paginate the results

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

**Tech**: geofirestore, firestore, angular version 7

**Link** to geofirestore: https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js

**Currently:**

I'm using limit and increasing it 20 at a time.

**Problem:**

Its not really good enough since it calls bigger payloads each time and then orders them again as the list grows in ascending so its really confusing for the user.

Please let me know of any alternatives to paginating geofire?

**Current attempt:**

```
public getResults(geo: any, lastLimit: number) {
  const geocollection: GeoCollectionReference = this.geofirestore.collection('test');
  const query = geocollection.near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(geo.lat, geo.lng), radius: geo.radius });
  lastLimit = lastLimit + 2;

  return query.limit(lastLimit).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    return this.mapResponse(querySnapshot, lastLimit);
  });
}


public mapResponse(querySnapshot: GeoQuerySnapshot, lastLimit: number): any {
   let jobs = [];

   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    jobs = [ ...jobs, doc.data() ];
 });

 return { jobs, lastLimit };
}
```

**Questions:**

1. When will pagination be available if it's not?
2. How can I get around this for now if it's not available?
3. If it's available how do I do it, normally I use startAt / startAfter etc?

Comment: What order do you expect the results to be in? Because if you expect to get the 20 closest results first, and then the next 20 order by distance, that won't be possible without significantly changing how GeoFire/GeoFirestore works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54603092

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I would like to order them by closest to the lat and lng searched for in e.g. radius 10 lets say. but it doesnt let me do an orderBy or startAt for geofire

Comment: That is correct, there is no way to get the closest results only. See my linked answer as to why that is. Feel free to file a feature request against the GeoFirestore library that you use. But given how geoqueries work in these libraries, is is extremely unlikely that somebody will find a way to implement "nearest" on top of them without simply reading everything in range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In order to sort geoquery results by distance must I read the entire dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600722/in-order-to-sort-geoquery-results-by-distance-must-i-read-the-entire-dataset)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see what you mean. Is their a way to do any pagination for geofire?

Comment: Sure. Load all documents in range, order them by distance, take the first 20. That's precisely what my linked answer describes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have over 12,000 records. Thats going to cost me a lot of money per month. any other alternatives

Comment: So the limit function on `geofirestore` ends up [sorting the results in order of their distance](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js/blob/v3.2.1/src/GeoJoinerOnSnapshot.ts#L59) and cuts off results that are larger than the limit while keeping only the closest document. 

However Frank is right that how geoqueries work. Geofirestore (and geofire) scans geohashes around the coords you input. That way if you're point is by the borderline of where a hash could be we don't miss areas right outside of that hash. We have to query more docs to make sure we get the ones near your point.

Answer (score 0):

To Retrive the List of items from center location with the given radius limited to a certain number of items.

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

/*Create two object to pass location and distance for radius*/
val centerLocation = Location(centerLatitude, centerLongitude)
val distanceForRadius = Distance(1.0, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS) // or you can set unit as DistanceUnit.MILES if you want to find for 1 mile

val geoQuery = GeoQuery()
        .collection("users")
        .whereEqualTo("status","approved")
        .whereEqualTo("country","IN")
        .whereNearToLocation(centerLocation, distanceForRadius, fieldName) 
        //fieldName if you have passed at time of setLocation else it will take default as "g" if you do not pass
        .startAfter(lastDocument) //optinal (for pagination)
        .limit(10) // If you requires only 10 data per query
```

> Reference
> https://github.com/chintan369/Geo-FireStore-Query